# Query table based on array (SQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays

I'm currently trying to write up a query that does the following:

Take values we put in an array (in this case, emails, VINs and user IDs) and query our database. Bellow are examples of regular queries for each individual case:

```
SELECT * FROM cinfo WHERE email = 'test@email.com';
SELECT * FROM customer WHERE UUID = 'exampleuser1234';
SELECT * FROM cinfo WHERE vin = 'examplevin1234';
```

I've tried the following to read a variable with multiple values:

```
SET @test = ('test@email.com' , 'test2@email.com');
SELECT * FROM cinfo WHERE email = @test;
```

but this only returns the results regarding the first email.

Is it even possible to have an array in SQL?

I would also like to take these values and depending on the type of text (e.g. if it contains a @) it would run a query for emails, and if it's an uuid it would run a query for uuids. Is this also possible?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: SQL doesn't have arrays.

Comment: So my idea is just impossible?

Comment: You can use a table as an array. Put all the emails in a temporary table, then use `WHERE email in (SELECT email from temp_table)`

Comment: Well we can't really create tables right now so I'll just drop this idea.... We'll eventually use lambdas and buckets to make this work so I guess it'll be done eventually, thank you!

Comment: You could use dynamic SQL in a stored procedure to construct `WHERE email IN (...)` from a variable.